# Java/Spring - How to save large lists in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, gridfs

I'm running into the 16mb limit issue for MongoDB documents. I basically need to save an entity (Trades) that contains a list of transactions that can be arbitrarily long (can exceed 16mb in some cases). How can I do this? Is there any way to accomplish this with Spring Data MongoDB's MongoRepository which is what I'm currently using. Basically just calling this at the moment and it works when the list of transactions is small but not when there's tens of thousands of transactions:

`repository.save(trades);`

I've looked into GridFS but couldn't find any good examples because they're all saving large files like videos, photos, PDFs, etc, then creating InputStreams out of them, and calling:

`gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, "test.png", "image/png", metaData);`

Not sure how to translate that into my case.

Comment: You'll probably need to implement some sort of paging (or switch to a different datastore for this particular index).

Comment: Allow me to introduce to you, the bucket pattern - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1

Comment: GridFS is not a good candidate for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you store all your transactions reaching 16Mb in size, in the same document, you won't be able to search on them using MongoDB queries. Since you are planning to store more than 16Mb in 1 MongoDB document, I assume that you don't wish to query on them, so GridFS should be ideal.
To store your list of transactions in GridFS, you'll have to serialize your transactions object, create an InputStream and then store it using the gridFsTemplate command you shared. Sharing one way to do the same in the code snippet below. Converting the object to JSON String, to Bytes, to InputStream.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String resultString = gson.toJson(yourTransactionListObject);
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(resultString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
ObjectId objectId = gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, "yourUniqueId", null, null);
```